# React filter on value before creating new instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component like this:

```js
export default function RenderEditor(props) {
  const {annotation, onChange, onSubmit, categories, usedCategories} = props;

  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(categories[0].categoryName)
  const displayedCategories = categories.filter(category => !usedCategories.includes(category.categoryName))

  //this should be fixed so it also sets the category correctly
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown",(e) => handleKeyPress(e, setSelectedValue, onChange, categories, annotation, onSubmit, selectedValue))
  }, [])

  //this is used to filter the categories so only the availible categories are displayed

  return (
    <div style={{width: '500px', height: '350px', witdth: '50%', margin: 'auto 0'}}>
      <p>Editor example</p>
      <ValueSelection 
        setSelectedValue={setSelectedValue}
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        categories={displayedCategories}
        annotation={annotation}
        onChange={onChange}/>
      <br />
      <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
        <Button size={"xl"} gray onClick={onSubmit} style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
          <span className='appkiticon icon-plus-fill'></span>
          Submit 
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I want to achieve is to change this section:

```js
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(categories[0].categoryName)
const displayedCategories = categories.filter(category => !usedCategories.includes(category.categoryName))
```

...so that the `displayedCategories` are the default value in the state above without like such:

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(displayedCategories[0].categoryName)
const displayedCategories = categories.filt ...
```

I have tried to use the `useEffect` hook to filter the value, but I don't want to prop drill either. Any good suggestions on how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Might be my morning brain, but I'm not clear what you mean yet. Are you asking how to change `selectedValue` when `displayedCategories` changes (or more accurately when the `usedCategories` prop changes)?

Comment: Or are you just wanting to initialize `selectedValue` with `displayedCategories`? It's perfectly legal to do your filter logic before your `useState`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating `displayedCategories` before your `useState` statement does not violate the rules of hooks, so this is perfectly fine:

```
const {annotation, onChange, onSubmit, categories, usedCategories} = props;

const displayedCategories = categories
  .filter(category => !usedCategories.includes(category.categoryName))

const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(displayedCategories[0].categoryName)
```

Then, if you also want to change `selectedValue` when the `categories` or `usedCategories` props change, you can add something like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setSelectedValue(displayedCategories[0].categoryName);
}, [categories, usedCategories]);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, exactly what i was looking for